# Webpack import defaults seems to differ from documentation

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, import

I'm trying to import the `default` from a file that uses `export default`.  e.g...

```
export default build_class(.....);
```

Then I try to import that default using...

```
import DaClass from 'dafile';
```

According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) this should import the default export as my `DaClass` variable, and if I want the the module, then you use the `import * as daModule from 'dafile'` statement.

But in Webpack this seems to give me the module and not the default, which I have to access using the `.default` property. The Webpack documentation is a bit light on the importing of defaults, which I can understand is something just not commonly used.

**What is the definitive fact on this?**, as it's confusing working between conflicting documentation.   I would like to resolve this using the MDN approach, since it will be easier on this large project I'm refactoring for Webpack, and there's already a good week or two spent upgrading the 500+ files to the `export default` approach.

Comment: you have to use .default if you use require (common js syntax). in es6 modules you need not specify .default. import mymodule from './dafile' will import only  default exports

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the Class was loading correctly, what was wrong was Chrome's (v72.0.3626.121) interpretation of the `import` statement.

Using a good old `console.log(DeClass);` gave me the correct output I was expecting.

So basically Chrome's dev inspector gets a bit confused with reading import statements.   Also, I've noticed that inspecting `MyModule.default` property ends in a perpetual loop of the `.default` property (e.g. `MyModule.default.default.default.default.default....` you get the idea).

My issue turned out to be that when my class was refactored to export, the static function was missing, which was causing the error.  Just the misleading Chrome lead me to believe that it was an `import` issue.